# Objective-C - What to do with MainWindow.xib?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xib

So, after creating a new project in Xcode, I'm presented with an interface file, an implementation file and a MainWindow.xib file. I've read that view controllers are necessary for every "screenful" displayed, so my question is what is the purpose of the MainWindow.xib file?

At the moment it is the window that loads when you start the program, but if I set up a view controller and its associated .xib file with a screenful to display when the application starts, won't MainWindow.xib just be a pointless file?

(I'm very new to this and am trying to understand the basics).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have to use MainWindow.xib only if u use Interface builder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MainWindow.xib file contains the actual Window (which the System needs) in which your View Controllers are added on top (like Layers on top of each other, the Window is the Bottom canvas).

This window is specified as an IBOutlet to your main delegate. You can remove the MainWindow.xib file after rejigging a few things around but it's harmless to leave it in there.

Comment: Ahhh... so, the .xib associated with a view controller does not _need_ a window? It can merely hold views? I think that might be something that has confused me.

Comment: Your View Controller XIB doesn't need it's own Window. It can have it's own Window and other components (not only Views) but you already have one in MainWindow.xib which handles the Window so why make it more confusing?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, a Coca application needs a main XIB file (it's not a requirement, just a common practice).

It may not contain windows, especially if you are using view controllers to load separate XIB file.

In such a case, the main XIB file is usually responsible to define the application's menu, with their actions.